# Adding font links to ikiwiki template

Tags: templates, ikiwiki

I want to add the following to all the headers of all the HTML pages in my ikiwiki.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Romanesco">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,400italic,600italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,600,700,800,400italic,600italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,600,700,800,400italic,600italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

I tried to add those line in a custom `templates/page.tmpl.mdwn` but every time I deploy the wiki, those are not added.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$git_repo/templates` create a file called `page.tmpl` which is a copy of `/usr/share/ikiwiki/templates/page.tmpl` -- or where ever that file is in your local system.

Then, you can modify `$git_repo/templates/page.tmpl` to add whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have added [opengraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Graph) data on the HTML  of all pages using a plugin:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package IkiWiki::Plugin::opengraph;

use warnings;
use strict;
use IkiWiki 3.00;

our $VERSION = '0.1.4';

sub import {
    hook(type => "pagetemplate", id => "opengraph", call => \&opengraph_tags);
}

sub opengraph_tags {
    my %args = @_;
    ${args}{template}->param('OPENGRAPH' => 1);
    my ${title} = pagetitle(${args}{destpage});
    my ${url} = urlto(${args}{destpage}, 'index', '1');
    my ${image} = urlto('logo.png', 'index', '1');
    my ${type} = pagetype(${args}{destpage});
    my ${opengraph_title} = ${title} || ${config}{'opengraph_title'} || "ikiwiki";
    my ${opengraph_description} = ${config}{'opengraph_description'} || "ikiwiki";
    my ${opengraph_type} = ${type} || ${config}{'opengraph_type'} || "website";
    my ${opengraph_image} = ${image} || ${config}{'opengraph_image'} || "http://ikiwiki.info/logo/ikiwiki.png";
    my ${opengraph_url} = ${url} || ${config}{'opengraph_url'} || "http://ikiwiki.info/";
    my ${opengraph_tags} =<<EOF;
<meta property="og:title" content="${opengraph_title}">
\t<meta property="og:description" content="${opengraph_description}"/>
\t<meta property="og:type" content="${opengraph_type}">
\t<meta property="og:image" content="${opengraph_image}">
\t<meta property="og:url" content="${opengraph_url}">
EOF
    ${args}{template}->param('OPENGRAPH_TAGS' => ${opengraph_tags})
}

1;
```

Then on **page.tmpl** I added:

```
<TMPL_IF OPENGRAPH>
<TMPL_VAR OPENGRAPH_TAGS>
</TMPL_IF>
```

You may use the same approach for dynamically adding elements to the HTML  section of the pages, or you could do a simpler approach but harder to mantain which is hard writing HTML directly on the **page.tmpl** file.

- [Plugin page](https://ikiwiki.info/plugins/contrib/opengraph/)
- [Source code](https://notabug.org/hiatobr/ikiwiki-plugin-opengraph)

---

### About page.tmpl

From the [docs](https://ikiwiki.info/templates/):

> Template files are unlike template pages in that they have the
>   extension .tmpl. Template files are used extensively by Ikiwiki to
>   generate html. They can contain html that would not normally be
>   allowed on a wiki page.
>
> Template files are located in /usr/share/ikiwiki/templates by default;
>   the templatedir setting can be used to make another directory be
>   searched first. Customised template files can also be placed inside
>   the "templates/" directory in your wiki's source -- files placed there
>   override ones in the templatedir.

Make sure the **page.tmpl** file you are modifying is stored under the template directory. Look out for this option on the **wiki.setup** file:

```
# additional directory to search for template files
templatedir: /usr/share/ikiwiki/templates
```